# Video player with ads - JW? Flowplayer?

Tags: jwplayer, flowplayer

I'm looking for a video player that can show video ads (prerolls, using VAST tags).
Preferably it should have waterfall functionality so that if one ad source does not return an ad, it goes to the next source.

Can this be done using JW player or flowplayer? Any other player that I should be considering?

Answer (score 1):

JW Player supports this. Here is a demo of waterfalling for your reference:

```
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/33589/tag-waterfalling
```